# Issue with HTTP POST request in WebView using Flutter and InAppWebView

Tags: flutter, dart, http, webview, flutter-inappwebview

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently facing an issue with implementing an HTTP POST request inside a WebView using Flutter and the flutter_inappwebview plugin. I have successfully used the following code to make an HTTP POST request in Flutter outside of the WebView, and it works as expected

```
request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(''));
request.fields.addAll({
  'S2M_SITE': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'S2M_IDENTIFIANT': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'S2M_TOTAL': 'xxxxx',
  'S2M_REF_COMMANDE': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'S2M_HTYPE': 'xxxxxxx',
  'S2M_DATEH': 'xxxxx',
  'S2M_COMMANDE': 'xxxxxx',
  'S2M_HMAC': 'xxxxxxx'
});


http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

However, when I try to use the same logic inside a WebView using the flutter_inappwebview plugin, the HTTP request does not seem to work as expected. I have replaced the confidential information with "xxxxxx" for security purposes. Here's the modified code that I used for the WebView:

```
type here  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Hello")),
      body: InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
          url: Uri.parse('url'),
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
          body: Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(
            'S2M_SITE:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' +
                '&' +
                'S2M_IDENTIFIANT:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' +
                '&' +
                'S2M_TOTAL:xxx' +
                '&' +
                'S2M_REF_COMMANDE: xxxxxxx' +
                '&' +
                'S2M_HTYPE: xxxxxx' +
                '&' +
                'S2M_DATEH:xxxxxxx' +
                '&' +
                'S2M_COMMANDE:' +
                '&' +
                'S2M_HMAC:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
          )
        ))
    ));
  }
```

The issue seems to be related to the HTTP POST request not working inside the WebView, and I'm not sure what I might be missing. I have checked the documentation of flutter_inappwebview and tried various approaches, but I haven't been able to get it to work correctly.

Has anyone successfully implemented an HTTP POST request inside a WebView using flutter_inappwebview? If so, could you please guide me on how to properly make an HTTP POST request in this context? Any insights, examples, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: Hi @Moustapha, did you find a solution for this issue? I'm struggling with the same thing.